# NextJS 500 Internal Server Error when reload page with `/:id`

Tags: next.js

NextJS returns 500 on production, locally is working fine but i'm trying to understand what could be the issue, any idea?

Comment: I'd guess it's either a ```next.config.js``` config, missing/wrong environment variables, or the server failing to render the page in case you use SSR. Are you using SSR or pre-building the pages statically?

Comment: In this page i'm not SSR, i'm using useEffect for fetching data because there are to many usees

Comment: In next.js i have `{trailing: true, images: {domains: ['domain1', 'domain2]}}` and thats it

Comment: so in this case the pages are being pre-built, and the build would fail if there was something wrong with the code of the pages themselves. Can't really say anything more without seeing the code. If you don't SSR, then there must be something crashing in your API. maybe try inspecting your function logs inside your Vercel dashboard, or try wrapping everything around ```try{}catch{}``` blocks and logging the errors

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: did you fin the root cause? I'm having the same issue